# How do I dipslay the attributes of the tables from a lists of database tables when I click that table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, joomla3.0

```
<td>
                <p>
                <div class="column"> 
                    <p><b>SELECT A DATABASE</b></p>
                    <p> <?php echo$this->form->getInput('Database_1'); 
                    include "db1.js.php" ?>
                </div>
               </td>

               <td>
                <p>
                <div class="column" id="tbDiv">
                    <p><b>TABLES</b></p>
                  <select name="List of Tables" size="25" multiple id='table1' name='table1' title='List of Tables' class='inputbox'>
                  <option >Tables will be listed here...</option></select>
               </div><p> 
               </td>
```

This the code in displaying the tables in a list from a selected database. I want to display the attributes of the table when i click it.

Comment: as you have tagged jquery, use an `$.ajax`, then just write a PHP script which interacts with a database then query the selected table name and handle the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `ajax` and `php`

```
<?php 
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysql','root','');
 $dbs = $db->query( 'SHOW DATABASES' );
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
li:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#list{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
#table{
    float: right;
    width: 68%;
}
#main{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
table,th,td{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
th{
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="main">
<div id="list">
<select id="dbase" onchange="getTables(this.value)">
<option>Select databse</option>
    <?php 
     while( ( $db = $dbs->fetchColumn( 0 ) ) !== false )
    {
    echo '<option>',$db,'</option>';
  }
     ?>
</select>
<!-- displaying dropdown ************* -->
 <option id="bulk" onchange="drop(this.value)"></option>
</div>
<div id="table"></div>
 </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //*************update for displaying dropdown menu *******
    function drop(table){

  var table = table; 
  var db = dbase.value;
 var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
data.open("POST","list.php");

data.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(data.readyState === 4 && data.status === 200){
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = data.responseText;

  }
}
data.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
data.send('table='+table+'&dbase='+db);
} 
//***********end of update **********
 function getTables(table){
var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
data.open("POST","get_tables.php");

data.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(data.readyState === 4 && data.status === 200){
    document.getElementById('bulk').innerHTML = data.responseText;

  }
}
data.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
data.send('table='+table);
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

create get_tables.php

```
<?php 
 $dbname = $_POST['table'];
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname","root","");
 $query = $db->prepare('show tables');
 $query->execute();
 $tabe_in = 'Tables_in_'.$dbname;
 $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 while ($results != null) {
  // change <li> to <option> here **********
  echo '<option>',$results[$tabe_in],'</option>'; 
   $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }

 ?>
```

and res.php

```
<?php 
 $table = $_POST['table'];
 $dbname = $_POST['dbase'];
 $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table";
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname","root","");

 $table_headers = array();
 $results = $db->prepare($sql);
 $results->execute();
 $res = $results->fetch();

 ?>
  <table>
  <tr>
 <?php 
  while ($res != null) {
   echo '<th>',$res['Field'],'</th>';
   $table_headers[] = $res['Field'];
  $res = $results->fetch();
  }

  ?>
   </tr>

 <?php 
 $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
  $query->execute();
  $rs = $query->fetchAll();

 foreach ($rs as  $value) {
  echo '<tr>';
   foreach ($table_headers as $val) {
     echo '<td>',$value[$val],'</td>';
   }
   echo '</tr>';
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That would do. This is really a big HELP.

Comment: But it's nicer if I could put the tables on a form, something like <select></select>

Comment: you want `<select>` instead of list?

Comment: Yes. So that I can just scroll down even there are so many tables. I am using joomla! for this that's why I want my UI looks nice. I'll be using it in making a system for synchronizing databases of three websites.

Comment: i have updated my answer to use `<select>`

Comment: It just remove the bullets and didn't put it inside <select> and I the tables are not clickable anymore when I do your updated answer.

Comment: @Min-aGuro i have added comments to my answer, to help you with where you have to change to display `<select>`. first change `<ul id="bulk"></ul>` to `<select id="bulk"></option>`, then remove first part of the `javascript` before the function `getTables()` with a new function `drop()`.in your `get_tables.php` change `<li>` & `</li>` to `<option>` & `</option>` see my comments in the answer.